# Jquery callback function

Tags: jquery

I have a problem in creating a callback function. First, as far as I can understand, a callback acts like  a parametr which triggers when all the action in its "parent" function has finished. For example:

```
$('p').hide('slow', function() {
    $(this).show('slow');
});
```

At first `<p>` is hidden, and only afterwards it shows again.

How can I apply such callback in a random plugin?

For example a plugin looks like this:

```
 $.fn.myPlugin = function(settings) { 
   return this.each(function() {
    settings = $.extend({ onShow: null }, settings);
    $(this).hide('slow');  /*This action should happen first (First action)*/
    if ( $.isFunction( settings.onShow ) ) 
     settings.onShow.call(this);/*Callback should fire after First action has stopped*/
     }
   });
 };


$(document).ready(function() 
   $('p').myPlugin({
     onShow: function() {
     alert('My callback!');/*Both actions(element hiding and alert ) 
                             fire simultaneously, but I need alert 
                             to fire after element is hidden*/
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying a callback to work the right way, like in most jquery methods. $(document).ready(function(){*Evereything in here happens after Dom is loaded but not before, so it is a callback*/}); And I would like to know how to write a callback in my plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `callback function` is a function, which is passed to another function/method and gets called at some point.

If we create a function like

```
function mightyplugin(foo, callback){
   // big code block here

   callback.apply(this, [foo]);
}
```

we now have a function, which calls another function. In this example, it parses `one` parameter through it and calls our callback-function within the scope of `this`.

A call would look like

```
mightyplugin("Bar!", function(param){
    alert(param);
});
```

we pass an anonymous function (more precisly, a reference) to `mightyplugin()` and we can access our parameter in there, since we call that anonymous function with a scope and an array of parameters (which only holds the original parameter here).

Those constructs must already be implemented by a plugin, otherwise you need to create your own functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need a callback to be triggered only after mightyPlugin has finished doing everything else assigned to it

Comment: // big code block here sholud happen first, and only after that a callback should fire

Answer (score 4):

You can't apply it in a random plugin. If the plugin is not written to trigger callback functions when different events occur you cannot use them.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadAjax(paramUrl, paramData, paramType, paramAsync) {
    var result = ""
    $.ajax({
            url: paramUrl,
            data: paramData,
            type: paramType,
            async: paramAsync,
            success: function (res) {
                result = res
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Unexpected error: " + data.val());
            }
        });
    return result;
}
```